# Dotted half rest not working in 3/4 time in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond

I can write the following in the `violinOne` part in LilyPond 2.18.2 and it produces a quarter note rest in a pickup measure followed by a measure with a half note rest and then a quarter note rest:

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "english"
\header {
  tagline = ""
  title = "O Worship The King"
  composer = "arr. Zack Macomber"
}
#(set-global-staff-size 17)
\paper {
  indent = 2.0\cm  
  short-indent = 0.5\cm 
}
global= {
  \time 3/4 \tempo "Andante Moderato (c. 100 bpm)"
  \key g \major
}
violinOne = \new Voice \relative c'' {
  \set Staff.instrumentName = #"Violin 1 "
  \partial 4 r | r2 r4 
  \bar "|."
}
violinTwo = \new Voice \relative c'' {
  \set Staff.instrumentName = #"Violin 2 "
  \partial 4 r | g g a 
  \bar "|."
}
viola = \new Voice \relative c' {
  \set Staff.instrumentName = #"Viola "
  \clef alto
  \partial 4 d\mf | g g a 
  \bar "|."
}
cello = \new Voice \relative c {
  \set Staff.instrumentName = #"Cello "
  \clef bass
  \partial 4 d\mf | g g a 
  \bar "|."
}
bass = \new Voice \relative c {
  \set Staff.instrumentName = #"Bass "
  \clef bass
  \partial 4 d\mf | g g a 
  \bar "|."
}
\score {
  \new StaffGroup <<
    \new Staff << \global \violinOne >>
    \new Staff << \global \violinTwo >>
    \new Staff << \global \viola >>
    \new Staff << \global \cello >>
    \new Staff << \global \bass >>
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```

When I attempt to change `r2 r4` to `r2.` I get several messages stating `warning: barcheck failed` and my PDF output is incorrect.

How am I supposed to write a dotted half note rest in 3/4 time in LilyPond?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem in `2.19.81`. Perhaps it's something involving another spot in the score?

Comment: But to answer your question, you write a dotted-half rest exactly as you did: `r2.`.

Comment: I'll try uploading a short example that produces the warnings...

Comment: Why do you want such a rest? It would fill a whole bar. For that, you should have a whole-bar rest symbol. The Lilypond code should have `R2.`, not `r2.`.

Comment: @RosieF Yes, I did end up using `R2.` in particular for the whole measure. I was actually having the same issue with `R2.` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue seems to lie in how you input the anacrusis in each voice. In `violinTwo`, for instance, you only write `\partial 4 r`, and LilyPond uses your last-specified duration for this rest (and all subsequent note values).

So when you write `r2 r4` in `violinOne`, LilyPond uses the last-specified duration (`4`) for all values, and everything works fine.

But when you change it to `r2.`, LilyPond uses the duration `2.` for all subsequent input, because now *that* is the last-specified duration.

The `barcheck failed` warning isn't actually because of any inconsistency between `r2 r4` and `r2.`. Rather, the failed barcheck is because your anacruses are `2.`, which is going against the `\partial 4` you've set.

If you specify the durations for all of your anacruses, your score should compile just fine.